# RFC 5322 - Regex for validating email allowing a non-valid top level domain

Tags: regex, validation, email, rfc

I'm using [RFC 5322](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)'s simplified regular expression in my application to validate any kind of possible email addresses:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

But, i noticed that the string `test@test.t` is valid for this regular expression (tested on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/3bv42)):

[image]

According to [IANA](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt), none of the valid top-level domains contains only 1 character.

My real doubt is: is RFC 5322 a reliable source to get a email validation regex? May I use any other? Or `test@test.t` is really valid for some specific case?

Comment: There is no such thing as a valid email regex.  Some come closer than others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: You want your regex to validate against tlds?  That's not maintainable.

Comment: @ergonaut I don't know if i were clear, but with the RFC regex, the e-mail `test@test.t` is valid. My doubt is: can i allow an e-mail like that to be submitted and inserted in my database? Is that regex reliable?

Comment: Ask yourself that.  Is foo@bar.mom valid?  Will you accept that?